# onClick event not called when clicking

Tags: reactjs

React onClick event not working when clicking on glyphicon.

```
const SortableItem = SortableElement(({value, parentId}) =>
    <ListGroupItem bsStyle='success' style={{width:'300px',textAlign:'left'}}>
        {value}
        {parentId === null && <span className='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' style={{float:'right',width:'10px',height:'10px'}} 
        onClick={e => {e.preventDefault(); console.log('yes')}}/>}
    </ListGroupItem>
);
```

Comment: Looks like there is nothing in your span element. Therefore it has a width of 0 pixels unless you fill it elsewhere or set a specified width and height with css.

Comment: i tried as you can see in edited code but still it's not working

Comment: Does your code not work either without code from react.js?

Comment: No my codes working fine but just onClick event is't firing

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it's hard to help you. Please post [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar. My `onClick` events on my `<a>` elements were not getting triggered when a user clicked them.

This is what I was doing wrong and *maybe* you are doing the same mistake as what I was doing. Without more context, it's impossible to diagnose what your actual problem is.

(code is basically saying, when I click the background, stop propagation of the click)

```
// Example of what I was doing WRONG

const Dialog = ({ onClose, children }) => {
    const $overlay = React.useRef(null)

    // on mount
    React.useEffect(() => {

        const handleBackgroundClick = (e) => {
            e.stopPropagation() // <<-- This was the line causing the issue
            onClose()
        })

        $overlay.current?.addEventListener('click', handleBackgroundClick)

        // on unmount
        return () => {
          $overlay.current?.removeEventListener('click', handleBackgroundClick)
        }
    }, [])

    return (
      <div className="Dialog" ref={$overlay}>{children}</div>
    )
}
```

Basically what I'm saying is this:

**Do not use `event.stopPropagation()` directly on DOM elements in React**

The events need to be able to bubble all the way to the top level or in-built React event's will stop working.

I ended up getting around the issue by adding an extra div inside the dialog to act as the overlay.

```
// How I fixed the issue

const Dialog = ({ onClose, children }) => {
    return (
      <div className="Dialog">
          <div className="Dialog__overlay" onClick={()=> onClose()}></div>
          <div className="Dialog__content">{children}</div>
      </div>
    )
}
```

**Note:** These are simplified examples to demonstrate a point. The exact code used was more complex. Using this code as displayed here would cause accessibility issues on your website.